# Exporting symbols under a different name

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries

My situation is as follows: I need to build a library where I export a "wrapped" `strcpy` (please ignore how that is useful to me) which the only thing it does is call the standard (from `string.h`) `strcpy` but return `void`, instead of returning `char *`. Which means, I need to `#include string.h` but this will immediately give me `strcpy` and `gcc` won't let me re-define it as I wish, and build a `.so` shared library exporting only the new, wrapped `strcpy`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: The user does not need to use the return value from `strcpy`. If he ignores it, the behavior is equivalent to a void return value.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie things are more complicated, better ignore why I do this. In fact, I use a Haskell FFI which is strongly-typed, and furthermore, there are other functions which I want to wrap in a more complicated way, not simply ignoring their return value.

Comment: This sentence is likely not true: “I need to build a library where I export a "wrapped" `strcpy`…” What leads you to believe you have such a need, particularly that it needs to have the same name as the C `strcpy` but a different type?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is a library for internal use, for my compiler (written in another language, Haskell), not a public one. I am only interested here in how I could accomplish this special symbol-exporting property, not how/why I need this... That would be another talk...

Comment: Maybe somehow GCC can allow me to statically link and make the old `strcpy` disappear? And then, somehow allow me to "rename" a symbol function to another name (because obviously in C you cannot have two different functions with the same identifier, with same parameters, i.e. no overloading). Are there such options somehow for gcc?

Comment: Even if your C implementation can be made to permit you to define a custom `strcpy` (e.g., GCC can be told not to treat it has a known/built-in function), it will still exist in the object module and cause link conflicts with the one in the standard C library, unless you do not include that library in the link. So you are not asking a simple C question; there are link and other considerations, and you should give a broader context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why is this tagged both C and C++?

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed, I didn't say it would be an easy thing, but there would be some kind of internal gcc-flag, or pragma, to rename a symbol function, somewhere, somehow... About your first point, first of all, `strcpy` is not built-in/internal, but exists under `string.h` so I can perfectly generate a `.so` with `strcpy` if I don't `#include <string.h>`. About your second point, I can statically link with the standard library and also hope for a symbol "renaming" in that way, i.e. to `__strcpy__`. Finally, this is tagged as both C and C++ because some of the two might do it in a way...

Comment: Knowledge of `strcpy` is built into GCC. The fact that it is declared in `string.h` and defined in a library file do not prevent GCC from having built-in information about it and treating it specially. All of the functions defined in the standard C library are special in that the C standard permits a C implementation to rely on them having certain properties.

Comment: Sounds like an `Xy-problem` to me.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond problem solved, so no problem exists now :D :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mystring.h

```
extern "C" void strcpy(char* dst, const char* src);
```

stringinternal.h

```
void mystrcpy(char* dst, const char* src);
```

mystring.c

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include "stringinternal.h" 
extern "C" void strcpy(char* dst, const char* src) {
  mystrcpy(dst, src);
}
```

stringinternal.c

```
#include "stringinternal.h" 
#include <string.h>
void  mystrcpy(char* dst, const char* src) {
  strcpy(dst, src);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "mystring.h" 
int main() {
  char dst[3];
  strcpy(dst, "ab");
  return 0;
}
```

The standard `strcpy` is exported as a weak function and you can redefine it in your library.

For proper link your .so you have to disable standard libraries for linkage and list files in a proper order: strcpyinternal.o then required standard libs and mystring.o in the end. This will prevent from recursive strcpy call from your .so. Example for gcc can be like

```
gcc -shared -nostdlib -o my.so stringinternal.o -lc mystring.o
```

Comment: The problem is that I want my `.so` file to export `strcpy` as a name (but that will be `mystrcpy` in fact), and not `mystrcpy` as a name.

Comment: You seem misunderstanding. I made main.c for demo, that uses strcpy from your .so, not mystrcpy.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. Let me try this one sec straight away.

Comment: How do we compile these files into the `.o` counterparts? It happens that I get:

`In file included from ./stlib.c:1:0:

./stlib.h:1:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant`

and it refers to the line:

`extern "C" void puti(const int32_t n);`

And it shows that the "C" is wrong(?)

Comment: The code seems having errors before that line reported.

Comment: gcc -c mystring.c -o mystring.o

Comment: On compiling with `g++ -nostdlib -fPIC -c ./stlib.c` (using gcc was the reason I was getting the above `extern "C"` error), I get the warning: `./stlib.h:22:20: warning: declaration of ‘int32_t strlen(const char*)’ conflicts with built-in declaration ‘long unsigned int strlen(const char*)’ [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]`. It compiles correctly though, and it links with no errors, but when I override `gets` then I get a linking error: `/usr/bin/ld: stlib.so: version node not found for symbol gets@@GLIBC_2.2.5`

Comment: I simply erased `-lc` you wrote on the linking step, and it worked. Did you include `-lc` for some specific reason in there, that erasing it could potentially cause trouble?

Comment: If a function is built-in then `-lc` is not needed. I included `-lc` in the example for not built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you uses c++, you can define your own namespace eg:

in a my.h

```
namespace strcpy_v2
{
    void strcpy( char *dest, const char *src ); 
}
```

in the associated my.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "my.h"

void strcpy_v2::strcpy( char *dest, const char *src )
{

    auto val = std::strcpy(dest,src);

   // you should test val to ensure every thing is ok

}
```

The from the code that will link you .so. You can do:

```
using namespace strcpy_v2;
```

instead of

```
 using namespace std;
```

Comment: This does not seem to do what I want, because I want to directly use the new wrapped function from my `.so` shared library, not through a namespace... I just want to find a way to completely "hide" and "overwrite" the standard `strcpy` but using it on my wrapper...

Comment: Using the wrapped function could simply be done by doing:
using namespace strcpy_v2;

Comment: It's use will not be in C/C++ code, but another language that doesn't recognize namespaces (or at least, it doesn't do so simply...)

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` is a weak symbol with "C" linkage, so it's possible to override without errors

libstrcpy.cc:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C" {
void strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    auto real_strcpy = (char*(*)(char*,char*)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "strcpy");
    real_strcpy(dest, src);
}
}
```

Compile with: `g++ libstrcpy.cc -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC -ldl -o libstrcpy.so`

Verify `strcpy` export: `readelf --dyn-syms libstrcpy.so`

To use (main.cc):

```
extern "C"{
void strcpy(char *, char *);
}
int main()
{
    char a[10] = "test" , b[10] = {};
    strcpy(a, b);
}
```

Compile with: `g++ main.cc -o main -lstrcpy -L./`

Note that if you want to use the correct `void` returning declaration, you can't import any header that will define `strcpy` (the right way).

Comment: Great!! Can this also be somehow done with static linking, i.e. if I wanted to produce a `libstrcpy.a` and have embedded everything, not depending on `dlsym` to dynamically load `strcpy`?

Comment: If you want to do this statically without `dlsym`, you need to use S.M.'s solution (you can just put `stringinternal.o` into an archive library).